# MATLAB find the point of a value obtained using min

Tags: matlab, min

I want to match a time to the minimum value of TEMP found in an array that I'm reading into a struct from a netcdf file in a loop (that's doing a lot more stuff - no I don't want to get rid of the loop). I have the snctools so that's what I'm using for netcdfs.

Here's my current relevant lines of code:

```
%Get the netcdf file with file_string loading into MATLAB
nc=netcdf(file_string);
%Work out the number of files I need to loop through
[files]=dir('*.nc');
max1=length(files);

for d1=1:max1
%extract the TEMP 1-D array
B1=nc{'TEMP'}(:)
%assign to value
dat.TEMP_min(d1)= min(B1);
end
```

Now there is another variable of the same length called 'TIMES'. If min(B1)=10.5 and is the nth element of B1 then I want to locate the nth element of TIMES and save it as dat.TEMP_min_TIME. How would I go about this?

Please provide enough notes on any code so that a novice can understand it.

Comment: Read the `min` documentation: http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html

Comment: Missed the example before - thank you David for making me look again.

Comment: Unfortunately using this did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use inside your loop (sorry for pseudocode, not sure about your definitions of n and TIMES)

```
[M,I] = min(B1);
dat.TEMP_min(d1)= M;
if (I == n)
   dat.TEMP_min_TIME = nc1{'TIMES'}(I); %
end
```